# How do I define and use a buildType just for unit tests in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, gradle

I'm trying configure variable that represents a backend api server that automatically changes according to whether I'm in production, running on the emulator or running unit tests.  The inhouse api server  lives in the cloud is available via  https.   The emulator can reach  the dev api server at http://10.0.2.2:3000/  and  the  unit tests can reach the dev api server at http://localhost:3000/

I think that I've sorted out the production and emulator portion of this through  buildConfigfield and BuildType in the app build.gradle.kts (snippet attached below).   I have not been able thus far to convince unit tests to use a third buildtype that I am attempting to create.  My unit tests, instead of using the "local" buildtype that I have configured for it, is instead relying on the "debug" buildtype and  is  reaching out to 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost, and thusly failing.

My ultimate goal is for  my code connect to the contents of API_SERVER, which vary according  production, emulator, or localhost.

I tried setting testBuildType = "local",  but that doesn't seem to work for unit tests (I suspect, but have not verified, that this is for istrumentation tests). I also tried renaming  app/src/test   to app/src/testlocal  but then the test fails  to find my code, as the test framework is confusing  local as a flavor (which I don't understand yet) and the type.

```
    ...
    android {
    namespace = "com.my.application"
    compileSdk = 34
    testBuildType = "local"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.my.application"
        minSdk = 30
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField("String", "API_SERVER", "\"http://10.0.2.2:3000/\"")

        }
        release {
            buildConfigField("String", "API_SERVER", "\"https://www.prod.myapi.server.com/\"")
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
        create("local") {
            initWith(getByName("debug"))
            buildConfigField("String", "API_SERVER", "\"http://localhost:3000/\"")
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: I wasn't able to find a direct solution to this, but I did come up with a simple enough workaround:   Instead of using either of those, I instead connect to the api via the local network;   e.g.   http://192.168.0.4:3000/